# HEX code Scanning and processing

Tags: c

How to scan **multiple HEX values** from a **file** and store it into an integer variables(different for every row of HEX numbers). Considering 4 bytes for integer and 6050BD in row one and 8060EF in second row and So on.

Answer (score 1):

while there is row:
`fscanf(file, "%x\n", num);`